# Problem with reports after install

Tags: soql, sobject, custom-report-type, package-install

I've recently created a package and I'm facing an unusual problem. Basically, in my development org, this works:

```
        String report = String.valueOf([SELECT Id 
                FROM   Report 
                WHERE  DeveloperName = 'Report_Unique_Name' 
                AND NamespacePrefix = 'MyPrefix'].id);
```

But now I've created my package and installed it in another normal org and this isn't working. The Reports and Reports Types are there and removing "AND NamespacePrefix = 'MyPrefix'" doesn't work either.

Best regards.

Comment: Did you check the value of DeveloperName in the org that you installed it in? It may of added the prefix on to it e.g. `MyPrefix __Report_Unique_Name`. The best way of debugging this issue is to use the Developer Console in the Org with the problem. Running SOQL such as `SELECT Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix  FROM   Report` should show why its not working

Comment: Thank you, didn't remember to use the DC. I ran a similar query and found out one of the reports was missing (I fetch three of these) and since they were surrounded by a "try" clause, one of them was failing and obviously making the other 3 also not appear. Thank you very much!

Comment: In addition to the DevConsole, Salesforce also has the **Force.com Explorer** that's handy for exploring Objects/data.   http://developerforce.s3.amazonaws.com/media/forceexplorer/ForceExplorer.air   (though you can't query the Report object in the Explorer :/)